# Pointer to Type Cast & Dereferenced Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Learning C++ and unwinding someone else's code, this bit is confusing me:

```
ACCOUNTDATA *cd = (ACCOUNTDATA *)*pi
```

pi originally seems to point to a struct of the same type ACCOUNTDATA.

I've searched SO and other places for pointers-to-pointers, pointers and parentheses (order of precedence), and came across using parentheses like this to type cast. Now, I am not sure if it is a pointer to a pointer-to-pointer (and the parentheses are useless), or of this is a pointer to a pointer that has been type cast and dereferenced, or something else entirely.

ETA: The is as abridged as I can make the relevant code:

```
typedef struct ACCOUNTDATA_
{
    //declare member data here
}ACCOUNTDATA;

//unrelated code here

BOOL SDMessage(DWORD objID, DWORD *pi, UINT messageID, DWORD param1, DWORD param2)
{
switch (messageID)
{
case SD_CREATE_PLUGIN:
ACCOUNTDATA *cd = (ACCOUNTDATA *)malloc(sizeof(ACCOUNTDATA));

//initialize member data here

*pi = (DWORD)cd;

case SD_SAVE_DATA:

//unrelated code here

ACCOUNTDATA *cd = (ACCOUNTDATA *)*pi;
}
}
```

Comment: nobody can answer this without seeing what `pi` is and where it came from

Comment: This code will break if compiled in 64bit windows. Whoever wrote it is a noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pi` is a pointer to a [`DWORD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318.aspx), which is an `unsigned long` value.  Since explicit casts from `unsigned long` to pointer types and vice versa exist, earlier your code took advantage of it to convert an `ACCOUNTDATA*` to a `DWORD`, which it then stored in memory pointed to by `pi`.  Your line first dereferences `pi`'s memory, which contains a `DWORD`.  It then casts that `DWORD` back to `ACCOUNTDATA*`, and stores it in `cd`.  At no point was the actual `ACCOUNTDATA` object touched in the line, instead a pointer to a pointer to it was first dereferenced, then the dereferenced value of the `DWORD` storing the value of a pointer to it was assigned to another variable, with a cast back to the original pointer type.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. Big help!

Answer (score 1):

DWORD is not a C++ type, it's defined in < windows.h > as a 32 bit unsigned integer.
And pi is a pointer to a variable of DWORD type. It may have base address of a structure of ACCOUNTDATA type.
In this case my best assumption is that pi is working as pointer to pointer, which stores the address of a pointer which in turns stores the base address of a structure of type ACCOUNTDATA. So *pi is nothing but that base address only which is being dereferenced and type cast to pointer to ACCOUNTDATA type.

It is same as if you have stored the address of a structure in a generic pointer variable and passing the address of that pointer variable to some other function. So when you need to access that address in the called function you'll need to dereference and type caste that variable to particular type.

Answer (score 0):

pi has been type-casted to ACCOUNTDATA pointer type